# Fazendo ação em todos os dados

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de anúncios, onde é possível enviar ofertas ao dono do anúncio e depois realizar a aprovação ou rejeição da oferta, caso aprove e depois negociar com quem ofertou.

Me deparei em um problema: Quando tem apenas uma oferta eu consigo aprovar ou rejeitar, mas caso tenha mais do que uma oferta quando clico em alguma opção ele faz isso para todas as ofertas...

Dei uma procurada aqui pelo fórum, mas não encontrei nada parecido.

Segue o código (obs: quando joguei o código aqui ele bagunçou a identação):

```
            <div class="container2">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="titulo_1">
                        <h1>Ofertas recebidas</h1>
                        </br>
                            </div> 

                                <?php 
                                $id_usuario = $_SESSION["id"];
                                $anuncio = $_GET["id"];

                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ofertas = OF 
                                INNER JOIN anuncios = AN
                                ON OF.id_anuncio = AN.ID
                                WHERE AN.id_usuario = '$id_usuario' AND OF.status = 'ANALISE'";

                                while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
                                { ?>

                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    </br>
                                    <div class="text-center"><strong>ID do usuário que enviou a oferta: </strong><?php echo $sql['id_usuario_oferta']; ?></div>
                                    <div class="text-center"><strong>ID da oferta: </strong><?php echo $sql['ID_OF']; ?></div>
                                    <div class="text-center"><strong>ID do anúncio: </strong><?php echo $sql['ID']; ?></div>
                                    <div class="text-center"><strong>Usuário que enviou a oferta: </strong><?php echo $sql['nomeusuario_oferta']; ?></div>
                                    <div class="text-center"><strong>Produto: </strong><?php echo $sql['produto']; ?></div>
                                    <div class="text-center"><strong>Valor oferta: </strong><?php echo $sql['valoroferta']; ?></div>
                                    <div class="text-center"><strong>Valor de recompensa que você informou: </strong><?php echo $sql['valorrecompensa']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Viagem que ele irá fazer: </strong><?php echo $sql['viagemcompra']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Comentário: </strong><?php echo $sql['comentario']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Oferta enviada em: </strong><?php echo $sql['dataoferta']; ?></div>
                        </br>

            <form method="post" action="">
         <button type="submit" name="aceitar" id="aceitar" value="NEGOCIACAO"class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Aceitar</button> 
         <button type="submit" name="rejeitar" id="rejeitar" value="REJEITADO" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat">Rejeitar</button>
     </form>

                   <?php
                $IDoferta = $sql['ID_OF'];
                if(isset($_POST['aceitar'])) {
          $query = "UPDATE ofertas SET status = 'NEGOCIACAO' WHERE ID_OF = '$IDoferta'";
             mysql_query($query);
             echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0, url=index.php'";
       } ?>

   <?php
         $IDoferta = $sql['ID_OF'];         
        if(isset($_POST['rejeitar'])) {
            $query = "UPDATE ofertas SET status = 'REJEITADO' WHERE ID_OF = '$IDoferta' LIMIT 1";
            mysql_query($query);
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0, url=index.php'";
      } ?>

            </div>
    <?php

} ?>    
                </div>
```

Comment: Esse erro geralmente acontece quando tem um erro na cláusula `where` do sql, que em vez de fazer a alteração em uma linha do banco, pelo id por exemplo, faz isso a todas linhas. Acho que o erro está depois do where. Troque o `'$IDoferta'` por `" + $IDoferta + "`

Comment: Opa Guilherme, muito obrigado amigo! Consegui resolver com a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

Como o if que verifica se existe `$_POST['aceitar']` está dentro do laço while, independente da oferta escolhida ele é executado para todas as linhas do banco. Uma forma de evitar isso é tirar os ifs que checam por `$_POST['aceitar']` e `$_POST['rejeitar']` de dentro do laço while e colocar um input do tipo hidden dentro do form junto com os botões aceitar e rejeitar (serve para enviar o id da opção escolhida). Veja como fica:

```
<div class="container2">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="titulo_1">
            <h1>Ofertas recebidas</h1>
            </br>
                </div> 

                    <?php 
                    $id_usuario = $_SESSION["id"];
                    $anuncio = $_GET["id"];

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ofertas = OF 
                    INNER JOIN anuncios = AN
                    ON OF.id_anuncio = AN.ID
                    WHERE AN.id_usuario = '$id_usuario' AND OF.status = 'ANALISE'";

                    while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
                    { ?>

                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                        </br>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>ID do usuário que enviou a oferta: </strong><?php echo $sql['id_usuario_oferta']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>ID da oferta: </strong><?php echo $sql['ID_OF']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>ID do anúncio: </strong><?php echo $sql['ID']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Usuário que enviou a oferta: </strong><?php echo $sql['nomeusuario_oferta']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Produto: </strong><?php echo $sql['produto']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Valor oferta: </strong><?php echo $sql['valoroferta']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Valor de recompensa que você informou: </strong><?php echo $sql['valorrecompensa']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Viagem que ele irá fazer: </strong><?php echo $sql['viagemcompra']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Comentário: </strong><?php echo $sql['comentario']; ?></div>
                        <div class="text-center"><strong>Oferta enviada em: </strong><?php echo $sql['dataoferta']; ?></div>
                        </br>

                        <form method="post" action="">
                            <!-- Adicione um campo oculto para armazena o id da oferta escolhida -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="ID_OF" value="<?php echo $sql['ID_OF']; ?>">
                            <button type="submit" name="aceitar" id="aceitar" value="NEGOCIACAO"class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Aceitar</button> 
                            <button type="submit" name="rejeitar" id="rejeitar" value="REJEITADO" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat">Rejeitar</button>
                        </form>
            </div>
    <?php
    } 
    ?>    
</div>

<?php
/******************************************************************************************
Verifique a submissão do formulario fora do laço while
******************************************************************************************/
if(isset($_POST['ID_OF'])){
    $IDoferta = $_POST['ID_OF'];
    if(isset($_POST['aceitar'])) {
        $query = "UPDATE ofertas SET status = 'NEGOCIACAO' WHERE ID_OF = '$IDoferta'";
            mysql_query($query);
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0, url=index.php'";
    }      
    if(isset($_POST['rejeitar'])) {
        $query = "UPDATE ofertas SET status = 'REJEITADO' WHERE ID_OF = '$IDoferta' LIMIT 1";
        mysql_query($query);
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0, url=index.php'";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo!!! Testei aqui e ficou perfeito! Muito obrigado meu amigo!